# after using parenthesis () my function not running?

Tags: javascript, function

My first code working but second code not working after adding () parenthesis after myFunction. What is the reason?

**Code1**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    status.innerHTML = "The page finishing loading made my function run.";
}
window.onload = myFunction;
</script>
<h3 id="status"></h3>
```

**Code 2**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(){
        var status = document.getElementById("status");
        status.innerHTML = "The page finishing loading made my function run.";
    }
    window.onload = myFunction();
    </script>
    <h3 id="status"></h3>
```

Comment: Actually it is running, but straight away not `onload` - check your console and you will see errors to do with setting property on undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.onload is an event handler and must be a function, not the result of function. of course you may leave parenthesis, but in this way your function myFunction should return another function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
    return function() {
        var status = document.getElementById("status");
        status.innerHTML = "The page finishing loading made my function run.";
    }
}
window.onload = myFunction();
</script>
<h3 id="status"></h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

In first case you're assigning the *reference* of the function which will be used in callback.

In your second case you're assigning the *value that is being returned by the `function`* which is in this case `undefined` as you're not returing anything.

`window.onload` or any event handler for that matter, expects a function reference to be executed on callback.